# change and shorten multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like:

```
profile = [[2001-05-01, 20], [2001-05-02, 23], [2001-05-03, 18], ...];
```

I need to create a new array and manipulate the second element of the array by a variable factor.

So I'm doing this right now:

```
array2.push(new_ar(profile, 20));
function new_ar(origin, factor) {
  var result = [[]];
  result = origin.map(function(item){ return [item[0], parseInt(item[1])*factor]});
  return result;
};
```

I get the desired array:

```
array2 = [[2001-05-01, 400], [2001-05-02, 460], [2001-05-02, 360], ...]
```

## Problem 1

Now I need to modify my function and give it a beginning and an end to only get a part of that array depending on a start and ean end value.
Something like:

```
function new_ar(origin, start, end, factor) { 
 ... code ... 
}
```

So `newar(profile, 1, 2, 20)` would return only the last two items of the array and manipulate it with the factor.

## Problem 2

How can I set different start and end positions.

I need to have the opportunity to create an array from 0-10th element and from 20th to last element for example.

I appreciate comments and answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.slice`

```
function new_ar(origin, start, end, factor) {
  var result = [[]];
  result = origin.slice(start, end).map(function(item){ return [item[0], parseInt(item[1])*factor]});
  return result;
};
```

Comment: would you have an idea for the above edit too (see problem 2)?

Comment: @gco, get the first 10, use `.slice(0,10)`. Get 20th to last, use `.slice(19)`

Comment: can I combine slice like `origin.slice(start, end).slice(end2).map...`?

Answer (score 1):

@gco

Same concepts..but little tweaked..it may help

http://jsfiddle.net/S2ejy/2/

```
 var profile = [
    ['2001 - 05 - 01', 20],
    ['2001 - 05 - 02', 23],
    ['2001 - 05 - 03', 18],
    ['2001 - 05 - 04', 25]
];
 $('span').html('With no start or end :' + new_ar(profile, 20));
 $('span').html( $('span').html() + '<br>With start and no end : '  +new_ar(profile,20,2));
 $('span').html( $('span').html() + '<br>With start and end : ' +   new_ar(profile,20,1,2)); 
});

function new_ar(origin, factor, start, end) {
var result =[[]];
start = start || 0;
end = end || (origin.length - 1);
result = origin.slice(start, end).map(function (item) {
    return [item[0], parseInt(item[1]) * factor];
});
return result;
```